# Access array with variable name inside php stdClass?

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass

```
stdClass Object
 (
   [tip1] => Array
    (
        [text] => <p>Test text</p>
        [format] => 1
    )
)
```

I am trying to loop of object of objects with array

```
for ($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
{
  echo $fromform->{'tip$i'}['text'];
}
```

never worked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use double quotes,

```
echo $fromform->{"tip$i"}['text'];
```

Or like this wiht single quotes,

```
$fromform->{'tip'.$i}['text'];
```

Answer (score 1):

php variables never get parsed within single quoted

replace it with double quote

```
for ($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
{
   echo $fromform->{"{tip$i}"}['text'];
}
```